# Continents geometry data / extracting contours of continents from country geometry

Tags: shapefile, convert, geojson, contour

I have an ESRI Shapefile data from Natural Earth ([Admin-0 Countries](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-cultural-vectors/)). I converted it to geoJSON format. There is no world or continents geometry there, only the county one. And I'd like to extract eg. only Europe contours, without any country borders. And there's another problem - what about Russia? I'd like to include Europe-Asia border in Ural mountains, and there's no such data in my files.

Now I'm thinking that maybe the whole idea of converting that NE data is wrong - I bet that somebody already done that and there's world & continent geometry available to download somewhere on the internet - but I can't find it...

Comment: 5 meter contours Europe http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/five-meter-elevation-contour-line

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for - it doesn't include Europe-Asia border.

Answer (score 4):

I found admin levels with all subunits for each continent and I combined them using QGIS.

Here is the geojson file if you find it useful.

https://gist.github.com/cmunns/76fb72646a68202e6bde

Comment: This file has a high resolution and a large file size (also gzipped), how could I convert it to a lower resolution?

Comment: Do you have one for the entire world as well?